# Microsoft QnA Maker API Error Resource Not Found

Tags: javascript, json, api, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am sending a POST request using JS for Micosoft QnA Maker API. But it is returning a JSON file with Error Resourse Not Found

```
{ "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "The requested resource was not found." } }
```

Although I am doing everything correct according to the API still getting the same error.

I am using the code in JS as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var params = {

"question": "is qna maker free?",
"top": 3
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","XXXX");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

This code is returning **alert("error")** and also showing the following message in console:

```
westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?question=is+qna+maker+free%3F&top=3:1 POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?question=is+qna+maker+free%3F&top=3 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am referring to this [link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9ba9)

I have seen that there Response 400 says that "Argument question is not specified." But I have specified the question.
What's wrong with my code? I am quite sure that there's must be something wrong with this in my code.

```
"question": "is qna maker free?",
"top": 3
```

When I visit this [link](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?Zepo)

It also shows the same JSON file with the error.

Comment: in your ajax call add dataType: "json"

Comment: The problem still not solved. OR can you please mention how to do this? @Liquidchrome

Comment: do you have a proper knowledgebase ID? i don't think XXXX will qualify

Comment: @Liquidchrome I have hidden the id using XXXX.

Answer (score 1):

you have in your code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        // Request headers
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","XXXX");
    },
    type: "POST",
    // Request body
    data: params, //replace {body} with the params variable
    dataType: "json" //add this line
})
```

You might also want to handle the response with success/error functions so it will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/XXXX/generateAnswer?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        // Request headers
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","XXXX");
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    alert("success");
    },
    error: function(e){
    console.log(e);
    }
})
```